# How to plan cassandra capacity planning for 1 host?

Tags: cassandra, cpu, plane

for EX: 5 user (who read or update data in Casandra) per second. How much RAM and CPU should be increased in theory?

Answer (score 1):

In production, our general recommendations are:

- a minimum of 3 nodes in each DC (even for a single-DC cluster)
- a replication factor of 3 for app keyspaces in each DC
- use `LOCAL_QUORUM` for both reads and writes

3 nodes with a replication factor of 3 can tolerate 1 out of 3 nodes going down for reads and writes with a consistency of `LOCAL_QUORUM`.

From a hardware perspective, we recommend a minimum of:

- 4 cores
- 16GB of RAM
- allocate 8GB to heap using CMS GC

For moderate workloads, 8 cores + 24GB RAM + allocate 16GB to heap. For heavy workloads, 16 core + minimum 32GB RAM + allocate 24-31GB to heap using G1 GC. Cheers!